# Apex Test insert is not setting a field on the record

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem

In my Test class, a custom field is not set when inserted:
The field Product_Family__c on OpportunityLineItem, while inserted, is missing when queried.

```
@isTest
public class tempTest {

    @isTest public static void TestTemp(){
        Account testAccount1 = new Account(Name='TestAccount1', Account_Type__c='Sales', Plan_Type__c='Professional', Licenses_Purchased__c=20);
        insert testAccount1;
        
        RecordType salesOpp = [Select Id from RecordType where Name='Sales Opportunity'];
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        Product2 testProd = new Product2(Name='TestProduct');
        insert testProd;
        PriceBookEntry testpbe1 = new PriceBookEntry(Product2Id = testProd.Id, PriceBook2Id = pricebookId, UnitPrice=90, IsActive=true);
        insert testpbe1;

        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(Name='TestOpp1', AccountID=testAccount1.Id, CloseDate=Date.today().toStartOfMonth(), 
                                              StageName='Closed Won', Amount=100,
                                              RecordTypeId=salesOpp.Id, Contract_End_Date__c=Date.today()+30, 
                                              PriceBook2Id=pricebookId);
        insert testOpp;
        
        OpportunityLineItem oppProduct = new OpportunityLineItem(Product2Id = testProd.Id, 
                                                                 OpportunityId = testOpp.Id, 
                                                                 TotalPrice = 90, Quantity = 1, 
                                                                 Product_Family__c = 'Product');
        
        insert oppProduct;
        
        OpportunityLineItem resultOppProduct = [Select Id, Product_Family__c from OpportunityLineItem];
        system.debug(resultOppProduct);
        system.Assert(resultOppProduct.Product_Family__c != null);
    }
}
```

Output of debug: `OpportunityLineItem:{Id=00k5500000DpeYgAAJ}` -- no Product Family

The assertion fails.
Permissions are set correctly on that field and it works fine on live records.
There are no validation rules or workflows that would change the value either.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, I am posting here as a last resort, as I've wasted hours on this already.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for posting your question and I understand the frustration! I just wanted to clarify what this test class is actually being used to test for if there is no automation that changes the value of that field?

Comment: create the OpportunityLineItem not with Product2Id but with `PricebookEntryId= tespbe1.Id`; Product2Id is auto-populated by SFDC from the OLI-PBE-Product junction

Comment: @CallumMacErlich This is an excerpt I created to isolate the problem.  In production there are some roll-up summary fields that filter on the Product Family field and they were not working in the Apex test.  They do work on actual records though.

Comment: @cropredy I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it still has the same issue in the apex test.

Comment: I'd look for some other automation (trigger/flow/PB/WFR) on OpportunityLineItem that is smashing the value

Comment: @cropredy Indeed a PB is what it was, I found it by reading the logs more carefully.

Comment: FYI you should use `system.assertNotEquals(null, resultOppProduct.Product_Family__c, 'some helpful message')` as that syntax will be significantly more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, as it turns out, was I missed an old process builder that was interfering with the inserted values, due to the order of operations.

Works fine when I removed that.  Thanks guys